# SmartAdmin Template Pagefunction runs twice Bug

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ajax, smartadmin

I am developing web application in smartAdmin Template, which is fully ajax based template you can check demo [here](http://192.241.236.31/themes/preview/smartadmin/1.9.x/ajax/index.html#ajax/dashboard.html). i am facing some difficulties in this template. when i write one javascript function on some page it works on all pages.

for example

```
$(document).on('click', '#elementA', function(){
 alert('Hello World');
});
```

works on other pages's element which also have same id, it is difficult to give different ids to all element as it is very large project and i am working on it since 6 months, so i thought about it and find out solution to give unique id to each pages and write script like this.

```
$(document).on('click', '#pageA #elementA', function(){
   alert('Hello World');
});
```

i thought i solved the issue but, isn't function stopped working on other page's element. but when i visit #PageA 2nd time the function runs twice. actually template stores all the user defined function in local memory storage (i think, i am not sure about this) and keeps storing, until we do not refresh whole template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok, after long R&D i solved this my self..
i used loadscript() function to prevent loading scripts twice unnecessarily..

i wrote all the script into one file (now i will have two view pages for one page.)

earlier it was like..
A.php -> JScript + PHP & HTML
now it is like A.php -> PHP & HTML, script/A.php -> OnlyJS

as i am using codeginiter framework, and dont want others too see js by accessing it through url, i used this process.

code on my view file

```
loadScript("<?php echo site_url('processor/load_script/path_to_folder/script/add'); ?>");
```

function on Processor controller

```
public function load_script($path)
{
    $last_segment = count($this->uri->segment_array());
    $path = '';
    for($i=3;$i<=$last_segment;$i++)
    {
        $path .= '/'.$this->uri->segment($i);
    }
    $this->load->view('core/ajax'.$path);
}
```